# Android ActionBar title does not change from PageChangeListener

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I got a `SlidingTabLayout` and I want to change the ActionBar's title every time I change tabs. I tried this:

```
tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() 
{

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) 
        {

             switch(position)
             {
               case 0:
               getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("title 0");
               case 1:
               getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("title 1")
               case 2:
               getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("title 2");
               case 3:
               getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("title 3");       
            } 

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
});
```

When debugging I do see the code being called, but the title does not change. When trying to set the title from other places in the code, it does work. 
What's the problem with what I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Activity OnCreate**

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Your code**

```
tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                 switch(position){
                 case 0:
                 getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title 0");
                 break;
                 case 1:
                 getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title 1")
                 break;
                 case 2:
                 getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title 2");
                 break;
                 case 3:
                 getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title 3");
                 break;

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Solve your problem?

Comment: the toolbar is part of a fragment activity.. its not a part of the layout itself

Comment: can you create a custom toolbar?? ill show you if you want

Comment: yeah I'm not sure how to create a custom one. The FragmentActivity just comes with an ActionBar of its own.. I'm not even sure why there's a need to set a new action bar if there's already an existing one.

Comment: btw, the main activity does not have a "setSupportActionBar" method. Also, the tabs are part of a fragment, which is one of many fragment inside a single activity.

Comment: Okey please show your xml activity and content, and show the full code of Activity and fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101601/discussion-between-fabio-venturi-pastor-and-jj-ab).

Comment: OK I found out the problem and kinda wasted your time.. sorry about that. I got no network connection where I develope so I couldn't paste the real code. The real code had switch case and my stupid mistake was not putting breaks in the end of each case..

Comment: If you edit your answer according to what I wrote (add something like: "another possibility if you use switch case..") and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Okey no problem, is nice if you solve your problem ;). I did the answers with switch. Thanks you.